# Issue with key/value pair in for loop: Cannot read property 'achievement' of undefined\n

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to get the current key of newAchievements in the for loop for (var key in achievementObject) after the line newAchievements.push?

For example, if the key of achievementObject is “Finish level 1”, is it possible to return the current key of newAchievements(which would be 0 in this case) after the line newAchievements.push in the same for loop?

Right now, I get this JavascriptException:

```
"StackTrace": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'achievement' of undefined\n    at handlers.UpdateAchievementsReadOnlyData (...-main.js:24:34)\n    at Object.invokeFunction (Script:116:33)"
```

I need to update the value of the achievement "Level1FinishTimes" with server.UpdateUserReadOnlyData(MyRequest); before I call ChooseanAchievement() for the next key/value pair.

Is it possible to get the current key of newAchievements in the for loop? If not, what would be the best way to update the value of an achievement(with server.UpdateUserReadOnlyData(MyRequest);) before I call ChooseanAchievement() for the next key/value pair?

```
handlers.UpdateAchievementsReadOnlyData = function (args, context)
{
    var achievementObject = args.AchievementObject;
    var achievementKeys = [];
    var newAchievements = [];

    for (var key in achievementObject)
    {
        achievementKeys.push(key);
    };

    log.info(achievementKeys);

    var getUserReadOnlyDataResult = server.GetUserReadOnlyData({ PlayFabId: currentPlayerId, Keys: achievementKeys });

    for (var key in achievementObject)
    {
        log.info("achievementObject[key]--->" + achievementObject[key]);
        newAchievements.push(ChooseanAchievement(getUserReadOnlyDataResult, key, achievementObject[key]));

    if (newAchievements[key].achievement != "")
    {
        log.info("newAchievements.achievement " + newAchievements[key].achievement, "newAchievements.addvalue " + newAchievements[key].addvalue);
        var MyRequest = {
            PlayFabId: currentPlayerId,
            Data: {},
            Permission: UserDataPermission.Public
        };

        MyRequest.Data[newAchievements[key].achievement] = newAchievements[key].addvalue;
        server.UpdateUserReadOnlyData(MyRequest);

        log.info("Updating achievement " + newAchievements[key].achievement + " was succuessful.");
    }
    else
    {
        log.info("Could not find this achievement.");
    }
};
```

}

```
function ChooseanAchievement(result, achievementkey, achievementvalue)
{
    switch (achievementkey)
    {
        case "Level1FinishTimes":
            if (result.Data.hasOwnProperty(achievementkey))
            {
                if ((result.Data[achievementkey].Value != null) && (result.Data[achievementkey].Value != ""))
                {
                    if (Number(achievementvalue) == 1)
                    {
                        log.info("Level1FinishTimes ok" + achievementkey + achievementvalue);
                        return { achievement: achievementkey, addvalue: Number(result.Data[achievementkey].Value) + Number(achievementvalue) };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.info("Level1FinishTimes" + achievementkey + achievementvalue);
                        return { achievement: achievementkey, addvalue: result.Data[achievementkey].Value };
                    }
                }
                else
                    return { achievement: "", addvalue: false };
            }
            else
                return { achievement: "", addvalue: false };
            break;

        case "Finish level 1 three times":
            var resultdatalevel1finish = server.GetUserReadOnlyData({ PlayFabId: currentPlayerId, Keys: ["Level1FinishTimes"] });

            if (resultdatalevel1finish.Data.hasOwnProperty("Level1FinishTimes"))
            {
                if ((resultdatalevel1finish.Data.Level1FinishTimes.Value != null) && (resultdatalevel1finish.Data.Level1FinishTimes.Value != ""))
                {
                    if ((Number(resultdatalevel1finish.Data.Level1FinishTimes.Value) >= 3)  && (achievementvalue == true))
                    {
                        log.info("Finish level 1 three times ok" + achievementkey + achievementvalue);
                        return { achievement: achievementkey, addvalue: achievementvalue };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.info("Finish level 1 three times" + achievementkey + achievementvalue);
                        return { achievement: achievementkey, addvalue: result.Data[achievementkey].Value };
                    }
                }
                else
                    return { achievement: "", addvalue: false };
            }
            else
                return { achievement: "", addvalue: false };
            break;
            //...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are pushing the new object to an array `newAchievements.push()` The last element is the latest achievement. So `newAchievements.slice(-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are misunderstood the terms `key` and `index` of an array. You are pushing an item into array. You need to use `index` to get an item of an array, e.g. `fooData[0]`:

```js
const fooData = [
    {'Finish level 0': 0, test1: 0},
    {'Finish level 1': 1, test1: 1},
    {'Finish level 2': 2, test1: 2},
];

fooData.push({'Finish level 3': 0, test1: 3});

// To get newly pushed item of array:
const maxIndex = fooData.length - 1;
console.log(`Newly pushed item of array:`, fooData[maxIndex]);
```

However, you can have a `key` in array. You need to use `key` to get an item of an array, e.g. `fooData['someKeyOfAnArray']`:

```js
const fooData = [
  {'Finish level 0': 0, test1: 0},
  {'Finish level 1': 1, test1: 1},
  {'Finish level 2': 2, test1: 2},
];

// To get an object by key from an array
fooData['someKeyOfAnArray'] = {'message': 'This is a message'};
console.log(`// Object by key from an array: `, fooData['someKeyOfAnArray']);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the difference between key and index of an array.

Comment: @Hobbit7 I am glad to help you!:)